How to do SQLAlchmey left join with ON statement having a subselect

class EmployeePayRate(Base):

    __tablename__ = "employee_pay_rates"

    pay_rate_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(User.user_id))
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(Company.company_id))
    pay_rate: Mapped[float]
    charge_rate: Mapped[float]
    active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default = True)
    deleted: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default = False)
    created_date: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default = text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    start_date: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True))


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(Company.company_id))
    full_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(75), default ='')
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), default ='')
    phone: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(25), default ='')
    lang: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(25), default ='')
    time_zone: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), default ='')

EmployeePayRate can have mulitple entries meaning someones charge rate or pay rate can change over time and when it does it is to pick up the one that is the most recent but less than the date given.  So if I did 8-24-2024 as the date requirement from the data below it would pick up the second one.
employee_pay_rates
67,37,1,2024-07-09 11:07:09,75.04,250.00,true,false,2024-07-09 11:07:09
73,37,1,2024-08-20 20:59:17,100.04,250.00,true,false,2024-08-20 20:59:17
75,37,1,2024-10-08 13:23:33,100.04,350.00,true,false,2024-10-08 13:23:33

users
37,1,tigga@myemail.com,1-ALAW-Z-1111222dd,(898) 404-2342,ENG,EST

Receiving this error:
InvalidRequestError("Select statement '<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x0000024EB4C4B320>' returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation; specify correlate(<tables>) to control correlation manually.")
            payrate_sel_stmt = select (EmployeePayRate).where(
                and_(
                    EmployeePayRate.company_id == User.company_id,
                    EmployeePayRate.user_id == User.user_id, 
                    cast(EmployeePayRate.start_date, Date) >= datetime.datetime.now().date
                )
            ).order_by(EmployeePayRate.start_date.desc()).limit(1)
            
            test_user_sel_stmt = select(User).outerjoin(EmployeePayRate, EmployeePayRate.pay_rate_id == payrate_sel_stmt).where(
                User.company_id == data["company_id"]
            )
            users = session.execute(test_user_sel_stmt)

this is the mysql query that works and I am trying to duplicate in sqlalchemy
SELECT u.user_id, u.full_name, epr.start_date
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN employee_pay_rates as epr on epr.pay_rate_id =  (select epr1.pay_rate_id
            from employee_pay_rates as epr1
            WHERE epr1.start_date <= '2024-08-24'
            AND epr1.company_id = u.company_id AND epr1.user_id = u.user_id
            ORDER BY epr1.start_date LIMIT 1)

 where u.company_id = 1


So what I needed was a scalar_subquery and use an alias for the sub select that was on the ON matching. The final query statement looked like this...I combined them.
    current_date = str(datetime.date.today())
    aliasEpr= aliased(EmployeePayRate)
    user_sel_stmt = select(User.user_id, User.full_name, User.email, User.phone, 
                           User.locked, User.last_login_date, User.active, 
                           EmployeePayRate.default_charge_rate, EmployeePayRate.pay_rate
    ).outerjoin(
        EmployeePayRate, EmployeePayRate.pay_rate_id == ( 
            select(aliasEpr.pay_rate_id).where(
                and_(
                        aliasEpr.company_id == User.company_id,
                        aliasEpr.user_id == User.user_id,
                        func.date(aliasEpr.start_date) <= current_date
                )
            ).order_by(aliasEpr.start_date.desc()).limit(1).scalar_subquery()
        )).where(
            and_(
                (User.company_id == data["company_id"]) & (or_(*or_conditions))
            )
        )

